# Spacing of prime divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The following question naturally came up when dealing with 4-rank of certain class groups. In this case I want to inductively deal with some Legendre symbols, and to do so I want my squarefree integers to be "decently" spaced in the sense below.

Is there an absolute constant $C > 0$ such that for all functions $f$ going to infinity and almost all squarefree integers $n = p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_r$ we have
$$
\prod_{i = 1}^k p_i < p_{k + 1}^C
$$
for all $f(n) \leq k < r$? What if we ask the question instead for almost all $k$?

Comment: What is $p_{i+1}$ in the RHS?

Comment: Should have been $p_{k+1}$!

Comment: And, I suppose, you need $k<r$ instead of $k\le r$? (What is $p_{k+1}$ if $k=r$?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true for the all $k<r$ problem.  Consider random $n$ below $x$, and put $z=\log x$.  How many prime factors would a random number have in $[z,z^e]$?  This is approximately Poisson with parameter $\sum_{z <p \le z^e} 1/p \approx 1$.  So with positive probability you would find numbers with as many prime factors from this interval as you care to specify, which means that no fixed value of $C$ would work.

Look in the work of Ford on the multiplication table problem.  There are different ways of phrasing conditions of this type; for example recasting it in terms of the number of prime factors up to some point satisfying a ``barrier" condition.  Perhaps one of those reformulations would be useful for you.